# iOS UITabBar items location

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Is there any way to create a tab bar in iOS with 3 tab bar items having these positions:

Tab1 - margin left equals 0;

Tab2 - centered horizontally;

Tab3: margin right equals 0 ?

[image]

I tried `UITabBarItemPositioning.Fill` and creating a custom UITabBar in order to find some methods/properties to override, but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Create a custom view with constraints instead, it's much easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TitlePositionAdjustment` in `UITabBarItem`.

You can set the horizontal margin or vertical margin.

Since `UITabbarItem` is not a `UIView` , We can't access its subview and can't get the frame from it , so we have to set different fixed values on different devices.

Ugly but it works:

```
nfloat TitlePositionAdjustment = 0;
if (IPhone4) {
    TitlePositionAdjustment = xx;
}
else if (IPhone5)
{
    TitlePositionAdjustment = xx;
}
//xxx and so on..

tab.TitlePositionAdjustment = new UIOffset(TitlePositionAdjustment, 0);
```

If you don't want this solution, I think you need to create custom view to simulate `UITabBar`.

[image]

Comment: In your example you are using -70, how do I know which value is correct for different screen sizes?

Comment: Have you found any other  solution ?@MadalinSisu

Comment: Unfortunately not